# ARCORE UNREAL ENGINE 4.18 PREVIEW 3

Tags: android, android-ndk, augmented-reality, unreal-engine4, arcore

I spend a day to packaging Unreal simple, but I did not succeed. I change my Android SDK and NDK 4 or more, but I have still have this bug. Please look at UEBuildLog.
I have a Google Pixel and I use last version of Google arcore, 4.18 preview 3

```
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): Module.SandboxFile.cpp [arm64-es2]
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): Module.NullNetworkReplayStreaming.cpp [arm64-es2]
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): Module.HttpNetworkReplayStreaming.cpp [arm64-es2]
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): Module.Analytics.cpp [arm64-es2]
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): Module.ReliabilityHandlerComponent.cpp [arm64-es2]
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): Module.DatabaseSupport.cpp [arm64-es2]
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): Module.Advertising.cpp [arm64-es2]
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): Module.ImageCore.cpp [arm64-es2]
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): Module.SessionMessages.cpp [arm64-es2]
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): Module.UnrealEdMessages.cpp [arm64-es2]
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): Module.ProfilerMessages.cpp [arm64-es2]
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): Module.EngineMessages.cpp [arm64-es2]
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): Module.Navmesh.3_of_3.cpp [arm64-es2]
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): Module.MessagingCommon.cpp [arm64-es2]
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): UELinkerFixups.cpp [arm64-es2]
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): Module.AutomationMessages.cpp [arm64-es2]
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): cpu-features-patched.c [arm64-es2]
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): android_native_app_glue.c [arm64-es2]
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): HelloARUnreal.cpp [arm64-es2]
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): UELinkerExceptions.cpp [arm64-es2]
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): HelloARUnreal-arm64-es2.so
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): E:/NVPACK/android-ndk-r12b/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin\ld: cannot find -lPhysX3PROFILE
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): E:/NVPACK/android-ndk-r12b/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin\ld: cannot find -lPhysX3ExtensionsPROFILE
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): E:/NVPACK/android-ndk-r12b/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin\ld: cannot find -lPhysX3CookingPROFILE
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): E:/NVPACK/android-ndk-r12b/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin\ld: cannot find -lPhysX3CommonPROFILE
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): E:/NVPACK/android-ndk-r12b/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin\ld: cannot find -lPxFoundationPROFILE
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): E:/NVPACK/android-ndk-r12b/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin\ld: cannot find -lPxPvdSDKPROFILE
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): E:/NVPACK/android-ndk-r12b/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin\ld: cannot find -lPsFastXmlPROFILE
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): E:/NVPACK/android-ndk-r12b/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin\ld: cannot find -lPhysX3VehiclePROFILE
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): E:/NVPACK/android-ndk-r12b/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin\ld: cannot find -lcxa_demangle
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): E:/NVPACK/android-ndk-r12b/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin\ld: cannot find -licudata
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): E:/NVPACK/android-ndk-r12b/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin\ld: cannot find -licuuc
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): E:/NVPACK/android-ndk-r12b/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin\ld: cannot find -licui18n
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): E:/NVPACK/android-ndk-r12b/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin\ld: cannot find -licule
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): E:/NVPACK/android-ndk-r12b/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin\ld: cannot find -liculx
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): E:/NVPACK/android-ndk-r12b/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin\ld: cannot find -licuio
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): E:/NVPACK/android-ndk-r12b/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin\ld: cannot find -lfreetype2412
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): E:/NVPACK/android-ndk-r12b/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin\ld: cannot find -lharfbuzz
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): E:/NVPACK/android-ndk-r12b/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin\ld: cannot find -lpng
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): E:/NVPACK/android-ndk-r12b/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin\ld: cannot find -lcurl
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): E:/NVPACK/android-ndk-r12b/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin\ld: cannot find -logg
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): E:/NVPACK/android-ndk-r12b/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin\ld: cannot find -lvorbis
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): E:/NVPACK/android-ndk-r12b/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin\ld: cannot find -lvorbisfile
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): E:/NVPACK/android-ndk-r12b/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin\ld: cannot find -lopus
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): E:/NVPACK/android-ndk-r12b/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin\ld: cannot find -lspeex_resampler
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): E:/NVPACK/android-ndk-r12b/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin\ld: cannot find -lPhysX3CookingPROFILE
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): clang++.exe: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)):
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): Error executing E:\NVPACK\android-ndk-r12b\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe (tool returned code: 1)
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): ---------------------- Done ----------------------
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)):
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)):
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): Took 1178.3000287s to run xgConsole.exe, ExitCode=10001
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): ERROR: Command failed (Result:10001): C:\Program Files (x86)\Xoreax\IncrediBuild\xgConsole.exe "E:\UnrealEngine\Engine\Programs\AutomationTool\Saved\Logs\UAT_XGE.xml" /Rebuild /MaxCPUS=200 /no_watchdog_thread. See logfile for details: 'xgConsole-2018.02.26-09.52.53.txt'
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): (see E:\UnrealEngine\Engine\Programs\AutomationTool\Saved\Logs\UAT_Log.txt for full exception trace)
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): AutomationTool exiting with ExitCode=1 (Error_Unknown)
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): BUILD FAILED
PackagingResults: Error: Unknown Error
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run Setup.bat if on Windows or Setup.command if on Mac.